# Jenkins - Load Statistics graph weird encoding

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have this on latest Jenkins but the graph legend is showing weird characters instead of English. Anyone know what could it be? Encoding?
This is the same even with other plugins that shows graphs.

[image]

Comment: This even happens with JavaMelody from the Monitoring plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Monitoring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem on a system with CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core), Jenkins 2.73.1, apache-tomcat-8.5.4, java 1.8.0_121.

You need to check the installed fonts.

```
fc-list
```

I solved this by installing the DejaVu fonts.

```
yum install dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch dejavu-sans-mono-fonts.noarch
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it.