# Jenkins Test Result Trend Graph Numbers Don't Work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm having an issue with Jenkins Test Result Trend. The graph appears when it needs to, however the numbers are no longer there and replaced with a bunch of symbols.

I am running the latest Jenkins (2.84) with all plugins up to date.

[image: Test Result Trend with Symbols]

I've tried disabling some plugins, triple checking junit plugin is fully up to date, and other various tasks.

Comment: The green color is from the Green Ball Plugin. If I uninstall the plugin, the chart returns to the blue color, however the symbols are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you've already resolved this, but for others - turns out this is related to the availability of the *dejavu-sans* font on your host.

I encountered this when installing *Jenkins* on *CentOS*.  Resolved with:

```
yum install dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch dejavu-sans-mono-fonts.noarch
```

See:
[Jenkins - Load Statistics graph weird encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699967/jenkins-load-statistics-graph-weird-encoding)